# How to show if user is a Subscriber

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the view I have a users table that outputs information on each user (registration date, gender, id, username, option to delete). I want to include an additional column on that users table that would output if the user is a subscriber or not.

The way to find out if the user is a subscriber is if their id could be found in the Subscriptions table under the `user_id` column.

How can I output this in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it the Rails way.

It seems, with your `User` model you have either:

```rb
has_many :subscriptions
```

or:

```rb
has_one :subscription
```

For the first one, you can check in your view:

```rb
<% if user.subscriptions.size > 0 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

For the second,

```rb
<% if user.subscription %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

To make it better, you can also add a method to your `User` model:

```rb
def is_subscriber?
  subscriptions.size > 0 # or 'subscription'
end
```

Then in your view:

```rb
<% if user.is_subscriber? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```